# Layout margin pushing image in ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-cardview

I am using grid view to display images in my app and I am using CardView for parent element. 
I want the CardView to have some space from the beggining of the page and between each CardView so I am setting layout_margin to be 5dp.
I also want to have some space between the image and the beggining of the CardView so I put contentPadding to be 10dp.
The result though is not what I want. It seems that the layout_margin is pushing the image itself and the padding for the right side is not 10dp as I want but 10dp - 5dp and I really have no clue how to fix that

Here is visual examples:

[image]

And this is the result I get:

[image]

You can see the right side of the CardView and how the image is not properly centered.

Thank you for your help!

Edit: 
ImageViewStyle:

```
    <style name="ImageViewStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/card_view_image_view_height</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerCrop</item>
</style>
```

Comment: please provide your `ImageViewStyle`

Comment: Edited the code

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/image"/>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. Same thing happens. Right side is pushed again.
If I remove the layout_margin it is ok but I need that space between the card views

Comment: It doesn't make sense at all, I just tried it and it doesn't happen on my side. Did you copy and paste my answer, the whole cardView? and where do you set the imageView background?

Comment: It is strange to me as well because I use another view which is not grid view but a recycle view and there there is no problem unlike here!
I am using Glide:

`imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
Glide.with(context)
                    .load(file)
                    .into(imageView);`

Comment: Can it be from the GridView layout?

`<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/dish_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>`

Comment: not sure if this will work, but its worth the try `<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/dish_grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        />` just copy and paste and let me know

Comment: you can also try `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` inside of the `ImageView`

Comment: You can also try and create a `LinearLayout` with `android:layout_width = "wrap_content"` inside the `CardView` and put above `ImageView` inside it.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the things work. I am really puzzled and have no idea why this happens. I really need to fix it but don't know where exactly to investigate

Comment: the last thing I can suggest is to replace above with [this](https://codeshare.io/argqvV). If that doesn't work then I don't know, there must then be some padding going on somewhere.

Comment: Not quite as I want. Nothing worked.
I tried setting layout_width to fill_parent for the CardView and it kinda work but I am not sure there won't be any future design problems this way